# Eagerly load all entities in DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there a way to configure a DbContext to eagerly load all of its entities? we have attempted:

```
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

We tried both with and without ProxyCreationEnabled being turned off.

I just happen to know that the DB we are loading in is not very large, doesn't change very often, and is referenced a lot. So keeping it all in memory will be very advantageous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `LazyLoadingEnabled` disabled does not mean "EagerLoadingEnabled". It is: "not even *lazy* loading enabled, only loading explicitly requested by you". An EF context will never automatically do eager loading. Just think what could happen with many associations between entities and large databases.

You won't benefit much from pre-loading everything into your context unless you use methods to access the local entities only. You can access local entities by [`DbSet.Local`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.local%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) or [`DbSet.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.find%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Just accessing a `DbSet` (like `context.Customers`) will execute a database query anyway. If lazy loading is disabled it may use local entities for navigation properties (called relationship fixup) but otherwise accessing navigation properties will also cause database queries.

It sounds like you should populate an object graph from your database, using a context, and cache it outside the context. Note that if you fetch the data read-only you may want to use the [`AsNoTracking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) extension method. (Like `context.Customers.AsNoTracking()`).

Answer (score 0):

Nope... but if you're looking for the most performant way to load bulk data into EF DbContext, I recommend writing a stored procedure that returns multiple result sets (one for each entity type).  EF will automatically hook up the nav properties when the entities are loaded into the context.

Here's instruction on how to do it from both the DB first and code first perspectives:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx